# is a While True or If Statement best to execute one function before moving to the next

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stuck on a simple issue. I am attempting to ask the user to choose a desired function from a list. This inputted user string will invoke the chosen function until it finishes running. (It is a lighting sequence). After this sequence ends, I would like to ask the user if he or she wishes to choose another function. If so, continue. If not, exit the code.

I cannot decide if a while true or if statement is the best to achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
# random functions
def rainbow():
    print 'rainbow'
def clover():
    print 'clover'
def foo():
    print 'eggs'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # here are some random initializations
    print 'ctr-c to quit'
    user_input = input("choose from the following: ")

    if user_input == 'rainbow':
        print 'generating'
        rainbow()
        rainbow()
        rainbow()
        user_input = input('choose another')
    if user_input == 'foo':
        clover()
        clover()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `while` loop here until you get a successful user_input, upon which you'll want to break the loop. Inside the `while` look you can have your if statements as needed. For example, in your above code, what happens if the user types in `"rainboww"`, it basically just exits the program. It'd be better to have it like this:

```
while True:
    user_input = input('...')
    if "good result"
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    user_input = input("choose from the following: ")
    if user_input == "condition a":
        do something
    elif user_input == "condition b":
        do something..
    elif any(user_input == keyword for keyword in ["q", "quit"]):
        # when meet any quit keyword, use break to terminate the loop
        break
    else:
        # when doesn't find any match, use continue to skip rest statement and goto the beginning of the loop again
        continue
```

while True can meet your requirement. you can use if-elif-else clauses to do different works.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have tried implementing a combination of both of your codes and they work, but I would like to implement a return to the user_input after any function is run. This way after the function, there is an option to enter a new choice.

Comment: user_input = input("choose from the following: ")  while True:
if user_input == 'colorWipe': print 'generating...'  colorWipe(strip, Color(255, 0, 0))  break '''here I want to implement an option to return to user input after the function is executed''' elif user_input == 'theaterChaseRainbow': print 'generating...' theaterChase(strip, Color(127, 127, 127))  # White theater chase break elif any(user_input == keyword for keyword in ['q', 'quit']):

Comment: replace `break` with `continue` if you want to returns the control to the beginning of while loop